# Using jquery calender control in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a ready-made calender control available at http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/#download/datepicker.zip.

The date picker's object is readily provided.

In that there is one example showing that the calendar control is attached with the text box but my problem is it works fine with the HTML text box, but when I try to do it with ASP it does not attach with asp:textbox.

my code is:

```html
<head runat="server">
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="DatePicker/cssdatepicker.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="DatePicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">


        $('#TextBox1').DatePicker({
            flat: true,
            date: '2008-07-31',
            current: '2008-07-31',
            calendars: 1,
            starts: 1
        });

  </script>
  </head> 
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>

         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">   </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you attaching using id or the element class?

Comment: Please post your code for the `asp:TextBox` and the JavaScript code.

Comment: inspect your textbox id in the browser and use that for $('#yourInspectedTextboxId').DatePicker()

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the Scripts tags below your HTML elements. Also add a `$(function(){ ... });` around the script. Read up on this at [jQuery .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

Then use `<%=(TextBox1.ClientID)%>` to ensure that you are always getting the correct ID. This wont make much difference in your project, but is good to know.

Also make sure you are including the version of jQuery, **before** the plugin, that is compatible with the plugin.

```
<head runat="server">
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="DatePicker/cssdatepicker.css" />     
  </head> 
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>

         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">   </asp:TextBox>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{PATH TO YOUR jQuery file}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DatePicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function(){

        $('#<%=(TextBox1.ClientID)%>').DatePicker({
            flat: true,
            date: '2008-07-31',
            current: '2008-07-31',
            calendars: 1,
            starts: 1
        });
     });

  </script>

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Sir copied same code you provided above and made the changes in the path but not getting the calendar. @Tim B James

Comment: OK, so you do have the jQuery file included? Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: Yes sir i have included all jQuery files included and also not getting any javascript error..

Comment: No sir i do not have any online page.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Trying out a basic example here http://jsfiddle.net/gchmb/ it doesn't seem to work. I would use the jQuery UI DatePicker. Check it out here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I checked that ..

But sir basic need is while selecting the date from calendar.

First Year should come. When one selects year, then months should come then after dates are display...

with this package(DatePicker) i am getting this but not working with ASP controls.

JQuery's DatePicker runs smoothly... @ Tim B James

Comment: Contact me through my website and I will email you back.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround.It seems this datepicker loves an input field to be present on the form.Strange.So I performed a little trick.Create a dummy input box , with an id and a class and hide it via css and voila your textbox can be attached to the datepicker. I still don't have an explanation why it has to work when  forced this way.It should  just work by default since a textbox is rendered as an input box.Your homework to figure that out....

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/eye.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2"></script>



        $('.inputDate').DatePicker({
            format: 'm/d/Y',
            date: $('.inputDate').val(),
            current: $('.inputDate').val(),
            starts: 1,
            position: 'r',
            onBeforeShow: function () {
                $('.inputDate').DatePickerSetDate($('.inputDate').val(), true);
            },
            onChange: function (formated, dates) {
                $('.inputDate').val(formated);
                if ($('#closeOnSelect input').attr('checked')) {
                    $('.inputDate').DatePickerHide();
                }
            }
        });




 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
     <input id="inputDate2" class="inputDate" type="text" value="06/14/2008"   style="display:none" />
     <asp:TextBox  ID="inputDate" runat="server" CssClass="inputDate" Text="06/14/2008" >   </asp:TextBox>
 <label id="closeOnSelect"><input type="checkbox" /> Close on selection</label>
</div>
    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Not getting the calendar. Tried the same code provided above. @Abide Masaraure

Comment: Yes sir it works but when i select the date from calendar it is not changing the text of text box(i.e. when i select the date selected date does not come in text box). And sir i want to implement the calendar which is displayed in Example1 of DatePicker package.
The image of that calendar is on http://i.imgur.com/0Y4iXZF.png.

Thank you....

Comment: You need a callback function to do that.I have updated my answer and it works .The check box functionality option is optional.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below code

```
 $("#MainContent_txtCopyrightYear").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: 'button',
                readonly: 'true',
                buttonImage: 'References/Images/calendar.gif',
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
```

What you have to do is go into source of your page in browser and find its id and just replace MainContent_txtCopyrightYear with that id.

Comment: I would never hard code a dynamically generated ID like this. If you want to get the ID, then use `<%=(TextBoxControl.ClientID)%>`

Comment: Ya James is right you can use $("#<%=txtJournalIdToMove.ClientID %>").

Comment: I have tried <%=(TextBoxControl.ClientID)%> but still not working

Comment: And .NET framework 4 generates the same id as in source code for code behind in browser..

Comment: @user2017483 `TextBoxControl` was just a reference to what ever your control id is.

Comment: Yes sir,

I have used the same what you suggested..

    $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").DatePicker({
               flat: true,
               date: '2008-07-31',
               current: '2008-07-31',
               calendars: 1,
               starts: 1
           });

but still does not working... @Tim B James

Answer (score -1):

As per your code it seems that you have not included any jquery files.

Comment: i have included all the jquery files available in example..

<script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker/js/eye.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker/js/utils.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker/js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2"></script>